# Sitecore User Group Meetup - Bratislava #1 2019

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

I am happy to announce first ever Sitecore User Group organized in Slovakia!

There will be 3 topics:

1. SUGCON 2019 Reflections – Peter Prochazka - https://twitter.com/chorpo - https://www.linkedin.com/in/chorpo/
2. Extend Sitecore Commerce – Vlad Iobagiu - https://twitter.com/SitecoreClimber - https://www.linkedin.com/in/vlad-iobagiu/
3. Practical Helix in Action - Tibor Csiba

Date & Time (CET): Tuesday, April, 16, 2019 6:30 PM

Venue: Accenture Technology Solutions – Slovakia, s.r.o., Plynárenská 7/C, 821 09, Bratislava – Ružinov

[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Czechia-Slovakia/events/260053124/)

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 7 days